Get project root path in Cypress test file
In a Nx workspace I have an app that I am testing using Cypress
In one of the spec files nested within a subfolder as below
${PROJECT_FOLDER}/apps/${APP_NAME}/cypress/e2e/${SOME_FOLDER}/test.cy.ts

I want to get the absolute path to a folder (dist) that is a sub-folder of the project folder
${PROJECT_FOLDER}/dist

How can I get the absolute path to ${PROJECT_FOLDER}/dist within the test.cy.ts file?
I tried using __dirname but it gives me cypress/e2e/${SOME_FOLDER}/
I want to pass this path to a Cypress task from within the test.cy.ts file like below
// test.cy.ts
 const filePath = 'path-to-file in ${PROJECT_FOLDER}/dist/some-file';
 cy.task('fileExists', filePath).should('equal', true);

Cypress task in cypress.config.ts file
setupNodeEvents(on, _config) {
  on('task', {
    fileExists(filePath: string) {
      return fs.existsSync(filePath);
    },
  })
},


The exact code depends on how you have set up your nx workspace, but the key is __dirname inside the task is an absolute path, whereas __dirname in the browser is a relative path (due to sandboxing security).
If you add a task you can convert the relative path to an absolute path
  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    on('task', {
      absolutePath(relativePath) {
        const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../', relativePath)
        return absolutePath;
      },
    })

Notes

windows path, use \\ separator, linux path use / separator
assumes cypress.config.ts is in PROJECT_FOLDER/apps/APP_NAME, otherwise adjust ../../ to suit it's location.

cy.task('absolutePath', '/dist/example.json')
  .then(absolutePath => {
    assert(absolutePath === `${PROJECT_FOLDER}\\dist\\example.json`, 'absolutePath is correct')
  })



So your test could pass a path relative to PROJECT_FOLDER, and have the task construct the absolute path.
const relativePath = '/dist/example.json';
cy.task('fileExists', relativePath).should('equal', true)

setupNodeEvents(on, _config) {
  on('task', {
    fileExists(relativePath) {
      const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../', relativePath)
      return fs.existsSync(absolutePath);
    },
  })
}

